# How do I resize a group object once I have resized objects inside the group?

Tags: visio

When I create a group, for example attaching two shapes together, I want to later optimize the spacing and size of individual components inside the group. This leaves extra space that can be removed from the group boundary.

I was wondering if there is a way to resize the group bounds without ungrouping and regrouping. I'm picturing a similar method like cropping an image.

[image: Before on left; After resize on right]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code you can use the [`UpdateAlignmentBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.updatealignmentbox) method on `Shape` or, via the UI, the same command is available in the *Shape Design* group of the *Developer* tab:

[image]